# Build Node JS app that takes a file upload and runs tests on it

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests

This is a general architecture/tech stack question.

I would like to build a Node JS app that can test user-uploaded code. Basically, I would write test cases and then I would make a front end where users can write their own JS code and "submit" it to the Node server, which would run my tests against it and return the result to the user.

Essentially the same as HackerRank.

I know this question is broad, but I don't have any idea how to implement this - I assume there is a package or a library that allows this, but I do not know what it is called or how to find such a thing.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying exactly what your question is?

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone do you have a suggestion where might be more appropriate to post this kind of question?

Comment: @JoshWilson how to execute code on a node server and programmatically run tests against it - aka how to take uploaded code and execute it

Comment: did you handle uploading file in your app?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a REST server using ExpressJS to upload the file to the server. Then fork a node process to run the file. Then use `eventsource` to stream the result back.

Comment: "folk a node process"?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Jailed](https://github.com/asvd/jailed) as a package that should be able to accomplish what you're wanting, or else other packages that exist that provide appropriate security measures. I would be *very* skeptical of an approach that runs arbitrary user-generated code without well-researched protections, as this code could be used to compromise your server.

You may also want to consider running the user-submitted code on the client rather than the server, which, while it does have its own security risks, protects your server from malicious code. Jailed also supports this.

As for the general architecture, for running on the server you should have the client POST the code to the server via the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)/AJAX, run the code through Jailed or similar, and include the output as the response to the POST. Running on the client should be simpler to implement (though for something like HackerRank you don't want to trust the client's word on whether they passed the tests).